# Neo4j Multi-tenancy

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, multi-tenant, tinkerpop

What is the best way to achieve multi-tenancy in neo4j?

I have seen Tinkerpop and Spring Data.

I'm have multiple clients and I would like to store client info in its own database to ensure security.

I do not want to use labels or indexes to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

You mention that you've "seen TinkerPop" but I couldn't tell if that meant you've seen it, considered it and dismissed it as a solution here, so apologies if that is the case and I'm not answering your question.

I've successfully used [PartitionStrategy](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#_partitionstrategy) (formerly [PartitionGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Partition-Implementation)) from TinkerPop to achieve multi-tenancy in Neo4j (and other graph databases).

You can read more about the approach here in this [blog post](http://thinkaurelius.com/2012/04/06/multitenant-graph-applications/) on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

Neo4j does not support multi-tenant deployments at this time. You can run multiple instances on the same server, each one on a different port.

Alternatively, you can use a managed hosting service like [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com), which provides secure independent instances. Disclaimer: I work at GrapheneDB.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the multi-tenant deployment and how it would work for multi-tenancy?