# How to achieve Multi-Tenancy in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

In my application i want to keep each customers data separately so wanted to know how can i achieve Multi-Tenancy in Neo4j.

As Neo4j does not support schemas on a DB as in ORACLE, is there any way to run multiple instances say on different ports on a single installation of Neo4j?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Neo4j Multi-tenancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927262/neo4j-multi-tenancy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to run different instances off the same installation.  The neo4j software is self-contained, so you can have two copies of neo4j in different directories on the same server with different ports.  In each you can separately configure the port in the `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file.  This also has the nice property that if you need to configure the two tenants differently for different usage patterns you can configure them separately.

Comment: Thanks Brian.   I have installed Neo4j on my windows machine and i am able to install two Neo4js in different directories but the neo4j-server.properties is at the path C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community. So both installations are using same properties file. Is there any way to separate the properties file for both as with same property file i can only run one server at a time.

Comment: Huh, if you used the windows installer it might have installed in a common place for all installations.  You might need to download the ZIP rather than the EXE from here: http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/ and unzip that into two different places.  There seem to be BAT files there which are similar to the UNIX executables.